# How to return array object in query scope method of a model class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel.

I use laravel 5.4.

I want to make my query scope method in a model class return an array object.

But, it seems that it returns query builder object instead of array object.

How can I return an array instead of query builder object in a query scope method?

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Carbon\Carbon;

/**
 * @method static VisitRecord create(array $attributes)

 */

class VisitRecord extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];


    public function scopeBounceZone($query) {

        $collection = $query->get();

        $bounceZoneList = [];

        $collection->groupBy("bounce_zone")->each(function($group, $key) {

            if ($group[0]["bounce_zone"] === 0 ) {

                $bounceZoneList["goal"] = count($group);

            }

            if ($group[0]["bounce_zone"] === 1 ) {

                $bounceZoneList["knock"] = count($group);

            }

            if ($group[0]["bounce_zone"] === 2 ) {

                $bounceZoneList["approach"] = count($group);

            }

            if ($group[0]["bounce_zone"] === 3 ) {

                $bounceZoneList["front"] = count($group);

            }

            if ($group[0]["bounce_zone"] === 4 ) {

                $bounceZoneList["detail"] = count($group);

            }

            if ($group[0]["bounce_zone"] === 5 ) {

                $bounceZoneList["closing"] = count($group);

            }

            if ($group[0]["bounce_zone"] === 6 ) {

                $bounceZoneList["hook"] = count($group);

            }

            if ($group[0]["bounce_zone"] === 7 ) {

                $bounceZoneList["finish"] = count($group);

            }


        });


        return $bounceZoneList;

    }


}
```

## edit

I don't want to have the code above in my controller class. My controller class gets fat, so I want to move it to a related model class. Any way to accomplish it?

## edit2

How come it doesn't add a value to the array in side of each loop??

```
public function scopeBounceZone($query) {

    $collection = $query->get();

    $bounceZoneList = [];

    $collection->groupBy("bounce_zone")->each(function($group, $key) {

        echo "it's called ok";

        // just a test.
        $bounceZoneList[] = 1;



    });

    //array(0) { } array(0) { }
    var_dump($bounceZoneList);


    return collect($bounceZoneList);

}
```

}

## EDIT 3

$collection = $query->get();

var_dump($collection->groupBy("bounce_zone")->toArray());

```
array(12) {
  [0]=>
  array(13) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(26)
    ["room_id"]=>
    int(14)
    ["project_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["bounce_zone"]=>
    int(0)
    ["bounce_reason"]=>
    int(1)
    ["next_action"]=>
    int(1)
    ["memo"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["staff_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["visited_at"]=>
    string(19) "2017-05-15 00:00:00"
    ["weather"]=>
    string(5) "snowy"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2017-05-15 15:02:35"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2017-05-15 15:02:35"
    ["deleted_at"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [1]=>
  array(13) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(51)
    ["room_id"]=>
    int(10)
    ["project_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["bounce_zone"]=>
    int(0)
    ["bounce_reason"]=>
    int(0)
    ["next_action"]=>
    int(2)
    ["memo"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["staff_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["visited_at"]=>
    string(19) "2017-05-15 00:00:00"
    ["weather"]=>
    string(5) "sunny"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(19) "2017-05-15 15:02:35"
    ["updated_at"]=>
    string(19) "2017-05-15 15:02:35"
    ["deleted_at"]=>
    NULL
  }
  
  and more!
    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `return $bounceZoneList->toArray();`?

Comment: Why do you want an array returned instead of the query to execute? Query scopes are about modifying the query before you execute it, not about returning data

Comment: @Antonis Tsimourtos it doesn't work.

Comment: @Mark Baker I see... But I don't want to have the code above in my controller class. My controller class gets fat, so I want to move it to my model class. Any way to accomplish it?

Comment: [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators) look like a better fit to what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try instead of:

```
return $bounceZoneList;
```

use:

```
return collect($bounceZoneList);
```

Comment: It's working! After returning array as collect object, to a controller class, I can change it to an array object :)

Comment: Do you know why  it doesn't add a value to the array in side of each loop? I added the code on my post.

Comment: what's return either of **$query->get()** and **$collection->groupBy("bounce_zone")->toArray()**?

Comment: I added the var_dump log when doing $collection->groupBy("bounce_zone")->toArray().

Comment: instead of `$bounceZoneList[] = 1;` try `$bounceZoneList[] = ['a' => 'something'];` and see the result

Comment: But when I add values to the array before $collection->groupBy("bounce/zone")->each(), it shows values in the array on var_dump log.

Comment: so, now it's working as you want? and paste the code of adding values before each()

Comment: no it's not working. it doesn't add value to an array in each loop.

Comment: $collection = $query->get();

        $bounceZoneList = [];
        $bounceZoneList = [1,2,3];


        $collection->groupBy("bounce_zone")->each(function($group, $key) {

Comment: I made a new post for this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43975166/how-to-add-value-into-an-array-inside-of-each-method-of-collection-object

Comment: I tried this in my controller class and it doesnt work as well.